# Deleting existing file to specific folder

Tags: c#

Good day,

I created a simple web application that can save a .csv file to specific folder on my web application..but i there something on my code that does not save it on my specific folder.I NEED to save that .csv file to that folder.

here is my code..

```
        protected void btnERSFRSWRSQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
             grdQueryTotal.DataSource =   _dVizOutputBll.GetERSFRSQRSQueryResultList(_totalValueTableEntities);
            grdQueryTotal.DataBind();

       string fname = "ERSFRSWRSQueryTotal.csv";

        string fLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/data/" + fname);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fLocation,true); //("C:\\Users\\jessr\\Desktop\\GTML\\GTML\\WebApplication1\\data\\gridview.csv");



        //if (File.Exists(fname))
        //{

        //    File.Delete(fname);
        //    sw.Close();
        //}
        //else
        //{

            for (int i = 0; i < grdQueryTotal.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(grdQueryTotal.Columns[i].HeaderText);
                if (i != grdQueryTotal.Columns.Count)
                {
                    sw.Write(",");
                }
            }
            // add new line
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            // iterate through all the rows within the gridview
            foreach (GridViewRow dr in grdQueryTotal.Rows)
            {
                // iterate through all colums of specific row
                for (int i = 0; i < grdQueryTotal.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    // write particular cell to csv file
                    sw.Write(dr.Cells[i].Text);
                    if (i != grdQueryTotal.Columns.Count)
                    {
                        sw.Write(",");
                    }
                }
                // write new line
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            }

            // flush from the buffers.
            sw.Flush();
            // closes the file
            sw.Close();
        //}
    }
}
```

but first i will check if the csv file already exist in my destination folder if that exists i will delete it, if not then i will save a new csv file

Comment: Your title is very confusing

Comment: ...and question too. Anyway do you want to save a file to an arbitrary folder? Well you can't unless you grant more permissions to ASP.NET user (because it can't write outside IIS folder). If path is still inside your virtual directory just don't forget tilde.

Comment: The code you've posted is also very confusing. Delete the commented out parts so we can see the working code. Also, fix the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `"/data/"` by `"~/data/"`, you should be fine -- if `data` is indeed the name of a folder in your web app's folder.

Comment: it still the same. it doesnt save in that folder..if i run my apps and debug my code. it run ok, but if i view the folder on my solution explorer the file is not there, but when i browse on the physical path, the file is there..

Comment: That is normal. In your Solution Explorer, you can only see files that are added to the Solution. Just because a file is saved in a folder, doesn't add it to the Solution.

Comment: ok, but can i access that file again on that folder? how colud i delete file if the file on that folder already exists? what's wrong on my code that was commented.. it does not delete that file exists..

Comment: Yes you can delete the file which was created even though its not appearing in the solution explorer. it means untill unless the file is physically existing you can delete it.

Comment: @CyberDaemon: there is no problem with commented delete file code , you are not giving proper path for File.Exists() , you need to pass fLocation as path variable instead of fname, check my answer for Delete code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `tilde` operator to represent the current Project `root` folder.

Try this:

```
string fLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/data/" + fname);
```

Note : make sure that data folder is inside your `root` folder

**Deleting file:**

```
       if(File.Exists(fLocation))
        {    
            File.Delete(fname);
            sw.Close();
        }
```

Comment: it still the same. it doesnt save in that folder..if i run my apps and debug my code. it run ok, but if i view the folder on my solution explorer the file is not there, but when i browse on the physical path, the file is there..

Comment: on the top of solution explorer there is button, show hidden.

Comment: it means it's working properly but you can not see using solution explorer..try as @Arun said.

Comment: Solution explorer doesn't add files like that, solution explorer explores the solution, not the physical directory. To add something to the solution, rightclick the folder, pick "Add existing" and browse to your file.

Answer (score 0):

use AppDomain.CurrentDomain

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "FolderName/")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your deletion code is that you're using `File.Exists(fname)`. Your program doesn't know where `fname` is, you need the whole path to the file, `fLocation`.

Comment: i tried your suggestion and i works fine. if the file exists it delete the file, but when the file does not exists the program does not step into else statement..

Comment: @CyberDaemon That's because you create your streamwriter, and thus the file, before you do the `File.Exists` check, so the file will always be there. Create the `StreamWriter` after you've deleted the existing file, in the else clause.